# LDAP connect SASL

Tags: java, ldap

I have bellow code and it's works.

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, server);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);
ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
```

But now my client told me that they will change his security to SASL.

How can I change it? , will I need a certificate?

Comment: Unless you tell what your client will you won't be able to comply.

Comment: I suggest you start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/sasl.html